# How do I upload a 3D model image for a product in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to upload 3D model image of a product that will be visible on frontend in product page.In magento 2.3, we can only upload image/video, but I want to upload 3D model for product also.Please anyone help me....!

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't support 3D model natively. You should look for modules that have this feature like Expivi, 3D Viewer. It may be useful but I have not tried them though.